# MATLAB: How to feed the current value from one system output as an input into a next system?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to implement a model system with MATLAB.

My model is composed of 2 subsystems as in the following figure:

[Link to the picture](http://picload.org/image/cdrdgrr/ee.png)
[image: forward-feed-ing system diagram]

**in short**: the first subsystem takes the angular accelerations and outputs the absolute angle ( `Phi`, `Theta` and `Psi`) given the Inputs `U2`, `U3`, `U4`.

The angle values must be now feed into the second subsystem, which calculates the position and respective velocities `( X, Y, Z, X', Y', Z' )`.

How can I *connect* both subsystem in MATLAB ( not physically in Simulink ) to get one unique system in which I give the angular accelerations and get the final `X, Y, Z` positions?

Right now I wrote this lines of code (really simplified I admit...):

```
M = 1.477;
Jxx = 0.01152;
Jyy = 0.01152;
Jzz = 0.0218;

% tf transfer function for the angles
s = tf('s');
G_phi   = tf([1],[Jxx 0 0]);
G_theta = tf([1],[Jyy 0 0]);
G_psi   = tf([1],[Jzz 0 0]);

% tf transfer function for the positons
a = (sin(psi)*sin(phi) + cos(psi)*sin(theta)*cos(phi));
b = (-cos(psi)*sin(phi) + sin(psi)*sin(theta)*cos(phi));
c = (cos(theta)*cos(phi));
G_x = tf([a], [M 0 0]);
G_y = tf([b], [M 0 0]);
G_z = tf([c], [M 0 0]);
```

where **`phi`**, **`theta`** and **`psi`** variables are calculated form the first subsystem, stored and then passed to the second subsystem to calculate the cos and sin functions there...

If I was not clear I will update my question
Regards

Comment: from your Figure, there seems `U1` to be also an input to your TF2( `U1`, `phi`, `theta`, `psi` ). Is this your final code-sample?

Comment: yes...I ve corrected it. U1 is only a input to my second subsystem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,I solved using Simulink.
[Here](http://ctms.engin.umich.edu/CTMS/index.php?example=Introduction&section=SimulinkControl) can one find a very good basic tutorial that explain very well how such equation are going to be implemented in simulink.

The way I posted above is really not the best one